# How to update the onclick event of the element using pure javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick

how to change **onclick="javascript:func-x()"**

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:func-x()" value="MENU" id="btn">
```

to **onclick="javascript:func-y()"** with same id on **javascript?**

```
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:func-y()" value="MENU" id="btn">
```

I've tried:

```
var c = document.getElementById('btn'); //input#btn
// ...
```

But I don't know what to continue...

Comment: Consider `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` instead, might make things easier to manage

Comment: id must be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `setAttribute` method, like this:

```js
function func_x(input) {
  console.log('I\'m func_x function');
  
  input.setAttribute('onclick', 'javascript:func_y()');
}

function func_y() {
  console.log('I\'m func_y function');
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:func_x(this)" value="MENU" id="btn">
```

Comment: @my0940 You're welcome. You can mark this answer as an accept answer by clicking on the check icon near by the upvote icon

Answer (score -1):

Javascript :

```
document.getElementById("btn").attribute("onclick","javascript:func-y()");
```

Jquery :

```
$("#btn").attr("onclick","javascript:func-y()");
```

Comment: close on first one but not quite right on method name